# Transition %cmake* (*.spec file) to cmake3?

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'd would like to transition an existing *.spec file from the fedora style `%cmake*` commands to the alternate `%cmake3` based one (eg. `Amazon Linux 2`).

What should I replace an existing `%cmake_build` with ?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
 % cat Dockerfile
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:7
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN curl -O https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/dcmtk/3.6.7/3.fc39/src/dcmtk-3.6.7-3.fc39.src.rpm
RUN yum -y update && yum -y install rpm-build make gcc-c++ cmake3 libjpeg-devel \
 libpng-devel libtiff-devel libxml2-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel doxygen \
 git-core
RUN rpm -i dcmtk-3.6.7-3.fc39.src.rpm
WORKDIR /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/
RUN sed -e '/0017-Increase-sleep-for-tests.patch/ s/^#*/#/' -i dcmtk.spec
RUN sed -e 's/BuildRequires: cmake/BuildRequires: cmake3/g' -i dcmtk.spec
RUN sed -e 's/%cmake /%cmake3 /g' -i dcmtk.spec
RUN rpmbuild -ba dcmtk.spec
```

Gives:

```
% docker build .
[...]
-- Build files have been written to: /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/dcmtk-3.6.7
+ %cmake_build
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.p5JL4r: line 70: fg: no job control
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.p5JL4r (%build)
```

And I do not see any `cmake3_build` command in:

```
# grep build /usr/lib/rpm/macros.d/macros.cmake3
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I used the following approach, seems to work out just fine:

```
RUN sed -e 's/%cmake_build/make %{?_smp_mflags}/g' -i dcmtk.spec
RUN sed -e 's/%cmake_install/make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/g' -i dcmtk.spec
RUN sed -e 's/%ctest/make test/g' -i dcmtk.spec
```

Hope this help

For reference:

- https://github.com/ligurio/FreeRDP/blob/6014efc19bf1cd6cd03d455c3df8cc88ac4f4022/packaging/rpm/freerdp-nightly.spec#L141-L145